# UIAnimations Disabled when orientation changes ios 9.2 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uianimation

I have updated the latest ios9.2 version. In have a `UITextView` in a controller. When I rotate the device when keyboard is visible, the `UIAnimation` is disabled. After this, all the navigations, transitions are happening without animation. Any solution available for this?

Thanks in advance.